# Python multiprocessing throws can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python, logging, flask, multiprocessing

I am trying to delgate a long processing task to background, so I can keep my UI responsive. Instead of using multithreading, which is not truly concurrent process, I implement my background task as multiprocessing. However I kept encounter error says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\engineio\server.py", line 411, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[event](*args)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 522, in _handle_eio_message
    self._handle_event(sid, pkt.namespace, pkt.id, pkt.data)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 458, in _handle_event
    self._handle_event_internal(self, sid, data, namespace, id)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 461, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "C:source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 490, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 251, in _handler
    *args)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\env\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 634, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\routes.py", line 171, in StartProcess
    myClassObj.Start()
  File "C:\source\MyApp\MyAppv\src\Controller.py", line 121, in Start
    p.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I am wondering where do I do wrong in using multiprocessing.

```
class MyClass(Object):
    def __init__(self):
       self._logger= logging.getLogger('MyClassObj')
       pass
    def Start(self):
       p = Process(self.Test, args(1,))
       p.start()
    def Test(self, number):
       print(number)
```

I am calling this class method from flask route.py, where

```
@socketio.on('StartProcess')
def StartProcess(msg):
    """"Do Processing"""
    myClassObj.Start()
    return 'OK'
```

This route.py is not the entry point of the my application, which this is called by runserver.py

```
from os import environ
from MyApp import routes
from MyApp import app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from MyApp.routes import socketio

if __name__ == '__main__':
   HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
try:
    PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
except ValueError:
    PORT = 5555
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=False)
```

I do keep seeing people mention the multiprocessing needs to run under a statement

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

But I am not sure how to correctly use multiprocessing in my case because at the entry point (runserver.py), I do not need my background process.

=== Edit ====

I created a very simple example to further elaborate this problem. My application has a simple flask app structure.

entry point runserver.py:

```
from os import environ
from MultiprocessDemo import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5100'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5100
    app.run(HOST, PORT,threaded=False)
```

route-level views.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template
from multiprocessing import Process
from MultiprocessDemo import app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from MultiprocessDemo.src.MultiprocessClass import MyClass

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
#socketio = SocketIO(app)

obj = MyClass()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Request To Fire Multiprocess."""
    return render_template(
        'Demo.html'
    )

@app.route('/TriggerMultiprocess', methods=['GET','POST'])
def TriggerMultiprocess():
    print('request to trigger')
    obj .Start()
    return render_template(
        'Demo.html'
    )
```

The MyClass object which create and execute multiprocess

```
#import queue #Queue as of python 2.x
from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import cv2
import os, errno, sys
import logging
import datetime
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # ==Where Issue happens ==========================
        self._logger= logging.getLogger('MyClassObj')
        self._logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        format = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - (module)s - %(thread)d - %(message)s')
        pass
    def Start(self):
        self.jobs = []
        self._nThread = 3
        for i in range (0, self._nThread):
            thread = Process(target=self.Test, args=('classobj',))
            self.jobs.append(thread)
        # Start the threads (i.e. calculate the random number lists)
        for j in self.jobs:
            j.start()

#bk thread to consume tasks
    def Test(self, name):
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            print('hello, {}'.format(name))
```

I found out that if the MyClass does not contain member of python logger, the multiprocess will be executed without issue, otherwise, it will throw the same error I've encountered previously. TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

However, for the same class, if I call them from the following script, without flask, I will not encounter any issue with pickling, whether or not logger is part of the class member.

```
from MultiprocessClass import MyClass

import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = MyClass()
    a.Start()
    print("done")
```

Comment: Please reformat the code in your question to repair indentation.

Comment: Did you  @user2386301 find an answer about the error?